# Random slow query performance in SQL Server 2016

Tags: sql, performance, sql-server-2016, sql-server-profiler

I will see you what is the problem...

```
SELECT 
    SUM(A.POSTEDQTY),
    SUM(A.POSTEDVALUE),
    SUM(A.PHYSICALVALUE),
    SUM(A.DEDUCTED),
    SUM(A.RECEIVED),
    SUM(A.RESERVPHYSICAL),
    SUM(A.RESERVORDERED),
    SUM(A.REGISTERED),
    SUM(A.PICKED), 
    SUM(A.ONORDER),
    SUM(A.ORDERED),
    SUM(A.ARRIVED),
    SUM(A.QUOTATIONRECEIPT),
    SUM(A.QUOTATIONISSUE),
    SUM(A.AVAILPHYSICAL),
    SUM(A.AVAILORDERED),
    SUM(A.PHYSICALINVENT) 
FROM 
    INVENTSUM A WITH(NOLOCK) 
WHERE 
    ((A.DATAAREAID = @P1) 
    AND ((A.ITEMID = @P2) 
    AND (A.CLOSED = @P3))) 
    AND EXISTS (SELECT 'x' FROM INVENTDIM B WITH (NOLOCK) 
                WHERE ((B.DATAAREAID = @P4) 
                  AND ((((B.INVENTDIMID = A.INVENTDIMID) AND (B.CONFIGID = @P5)) 
                  AND (B.INVENTLOCATIONID = @P6)) AND (B.INVENTBATCHID = @P7))))
```

[Query slow performance](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n0Fy8.png)

```
declare @p2 int
set @p2=180157421
declare @p3 int
set @p3=16
declare @p4 int
set @p4=1
declare @p5 int
set @p5=1
exec sp_cursorexecute 1073741895,@p2 output,@p3 output,@p4 output,@p5 output,N'ens',N'V89710821',0,N'ens',N'PO16628',N'AS',N'OFS028748'
select @p2, @p3, @p4, @p5
```

[Query parameters slow performance](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P2bWc.png)

```
SELECT SUM(A.POSTEDQTY),SUM(A.POSTEDVALUE),SUM(A.PHYSICALVALUE),SUM(A.DEDUCTED),SUM(A.RECEIVED),SUM(A.RESERVPHYSICAL),SUM(A.RESERVORDERED),SUM(A.REGISTERED),SUM(A.PICKED),SUM(A.ONORDER),SUM(A.ORDERED),SUM(A.ARRIVED),SUM(A.QUOTATIONRECEIPT),SUM(A.QUOTATIONISSUE),SUM(A.AVAILPHYSICAL),SUM(A.AVAILORDERED),SUM(A.PHYSICALINVENT) FROM INVENTSUMDELTA A WHERE ((A.DATAAREAID=@P1) AND (((A.ITEMID=@P2) AND (A.ISAGGREGATED=@P3)) AND (A.TTSID=@P4))) AND EXISTS (SELECT 'x' FROM INVENTDIM B WHERE ((B.DATAAREAID=@P5) AND ((((B.INVENTDIMID=A.INVENTDIMID) AND (B.CONFIGID=@P6)) AND (B.INVENTLOCATIONID=@P7)) AND (B.INVENTBATCHID=@P8))))
```

[Same query good performance](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i2Hdt.png)

```
declare @p2 int
set @p2=180157423
declare @p3 int
set @p3=16
declare @p4 int
set @p4=1
declare @p5 int
set @p5=1
exec sp_cursorexecute 1073741904,@p2 output,@p3 output,@p4 output,@p5 output,N'ens',N'V89710821',0,5666550353,N'ens',N'PO16628',N'AS',N'OFS028748'
select @p2, @p3, @p4, @p5
```

[Parameters same query good performance](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IWGU2.png)

In SQLServer Profiler you can see that the same query executes in 0ms or over 10000ms

And if I try to execute the same query (10000ms) with the same parameters directly it takes 0ms

What is happening?

Thanks!! :)

Comment: Don't make us read your profiler output. Get the code that is being executed and put it in your post instead of using 4 images and links.

Comment: Thanks! Edited! :)

Comment: you need to get the execution plans

Comment: It's also possible you're suffering from [parameter sniffing](https://www.red-gate.com/simple-talk/sql/t-sql-programming/parameter-sniffing/).

Answer (score 0):

The first time you execute the query, the db engine have to prepare the statement send to db search the data and return the result. The second time the statement is already prepared and the data is on the cache. That is why the second run is always faster

https://littlekendra.com/2016/11/25/why-is-my-query-faster-the-second-time-it-runs-dear-sql-dba-episode-23/

Comment: But the same query is executed a lot of times and first is executing ok, then poor performance and after good, it's a random problem I can't understand.

Comment: the other reason is usually a slow disk.